# iOS autolayout UIScrollView extra space to the right

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder, autolayout

Using `AutoLayout`, I am using a `UIScrollView` and everything seems to be working fine with my constraints, except that I get extra space to the right and can't figure out why!

Here is my structure in Storyboard:

```
View
   Scroll View
      Content View
         (all my other views go under here)
```

Is there an easy way to copy and paste my constraints here?

Thank you!

Picture 3 shows the constraints for the `Scroll View`.

[image][image][image]

Comment: What are the constraints for the scrollview and its container view?

Comment: Please tell what constraints did you gave to `Content View` to `UIScrollView`

Comment: Try adding the following constraints: the one you see above are the scrollview constraints. The descendants are of the content view. http://dropbox.io/file/c43ff0f0-591b-0132-3931-1231500501f9/original

Comment: @Anil I have updated my original post with the constraints list.

Comment: @Anil The dropbox file picture helped a lot! I have to add `Align Center X to SuperView`. Thank you. Please make this an answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following constraints: the one you see above are the scrollview constraints. The descendants are of the content view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try "trailing space to container" constrain....might be problem while adding constrain or You might change position of UI-element after adding a constrain.